# ¿Cómo eliminar una fila de un ASPxGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, delete

Estoy manejando DevExpress y tengo un ASPxGridView que lleno de manera manual.

Coloqué un GridViewCommandColumn para mostrar los botones de Editar, Guardar y Cancelar, sin embargo el de Borrar(Delete) no lo muestra.

¿De qué manera lo puedo mostrar? ¿O cómo puedo hacer para eliminar una fila del Grid pulsando el botón Suprimir?

Este es mi código:

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowEditButton="true" ShowUpdateButton="false" ShowNewButtonInHeader="false"  ShowCancelButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" VisibleIndex="0" Width="60" Caption=" " ButtonType="Image">

    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
    <EditButton Image-IconID="edit_edit_16x16gray">
        <Image IconID="edit_edit_16x16gray">
        </Image>
    </EditButton>

    <UpdateButton Image-ToolTip="Modificar" Image-IconID="save_save_16x16gray">
        <Image IconID="save_save_16x16gray" ToolTip="Modificar">
        </Image>
    </UpdateButton>
    <CancelButton Image-ToolTip="Cancelar" Image-IconID="actions_close_16x16gray">
        <Image IconID="actions_close_16x16gray" ToolTip="Cancelar">
        </Image>
    </CancelButton>
    <DeleteButton Image-ToolTip="Eliminar" Image-IconID="actions_deleteitem_16x16gray">
        <Image IconID="actions_deleteitem_16x16gray" ToolTip="Eliminar">
        </Image>
    </DeleteButton>

</dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se solucionó de la siguiente manera:

Dentro del HTML:

```
 <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="True">
        <DeleteButton Image-ToolTip="Borrar" Image-IconID="actions_deleteitem_16x16gray" >
             <Image IconID="actions_deleteitem_16x16gray" ToolTip="Borrar"/>            
        </DeleteButton> 
</dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

Funcionalidad del GridView RowDeleting:

```
protected void grid_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
    {        
        lista.Remove(FilaSeleccionada);
        Session["DataGrid"] = lista;

        grid.DataSource = Session["DataGrid"];
        gridArticulos.DataBind();
        e.Cancel = true;         
    }
```